# Search filter not working for multiple fields with common model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter, angular-ngmodel

I am trying to create a search box which can filter searches through various properties of an object individually.
In my current solution, I have to create a custom search function which emulates the built-in search:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="m1">
  <head>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="c1">
    <div>
      Filter
      <select ng-model="filterKey">
        <option value="bookId">By Id</option>
        <option value="bookTitle">By Title</option>
        <option value="author">By Author</option>
        <option value="cost">By Cost</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" ng-model="filterValue">
    </div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>SI. No.</th>
        <th>Details</th>
      </tr>
      <tr custom-tr ng-repeat="book in books | filter: bookFilter(filterKey, filterValue)">
        <td>{{ $index + 1 }}</td>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>Book ID:</td>
              <td>{{book.bookId}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Book Title:</td>
              <td>{{book.bookTitle}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Book Author:</td>
              <td>{{book.author}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Book Cost:</td>
              <td>{{book.cost}}</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var m1 = angular.module("m1", []);

    m1.controller('c1',function($scope)
    {
      $scope.books = [
      {
          "bookId": 101,
          "bookTitle": "Angular JS",
          "author": "Green",
          "cost":375,
      },
      {
          "bookId": 102,
          "bookTitle": "Instant AngularJS Starter",
          "author": "Dan Menard",
          "cost":150,
      },
      {
          "bookId": 103,
          "bookTitle": "Ng-Book: The Complete Book on AngularJS",
          "author": "Ari Lerner",
          "cost":4657,
      }];

      $scope.bookFilter = function(filterKey, filterValue)
      {
        return function(book)
        {
          if(!filterKey || !filterValue)
          {
            return true;
          }
          // Emulating the built-in search algorithm
          return String(book[filterKey]).toLowerCase().includes(filterValue.toLowerCase());
        };
      };
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

I would like to do the same thing without writing the search algorithm manually (and without needing to write much more code at the same time).

My current attempt at doing that is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="m1">
  <head>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="c1">
    <div>
      Filter
      <select ng-model="filterKey">
        <option value="bookId">By Id</option>
        <option value="bookTitle">By Title</option>
        <option value="author">By Author</option>
        <option value="cost">By Cost</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" ng-model="filterValue">
    </div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>SI. No.</th>
        <th>Details</th>
      </tr>
      <tr custom-tr ng-repeat="book in books | filter: {filterKey: filterValue}">
        <td>{{ $index + 1 }}</td>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>Book ID:</td>
              <td>{{book.bookId}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Book Title:</td>
              <td>{{book.bookTitle}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Book Author:</td>
              <td>{{book.author}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Book Cost:</td>
              <td>{{book.cost}}</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var m1 = angular.module("m1", []);

    m1.controller('c1',function($scope)
    {
      $scope.books = [
      {
          "bookId": 101,
          "bookTitle": "Angular JS",
          "author": "Green",
          "cost":375,
      },
      {
          "bookId": 102,
          "bookTitle": "Instant AngularJS Starter",
          "author": "Dan Menard",
          "cost":150,
      },
      {
          "bookId": 103,
          "bookTitle": "Ng-Book: The Complete Book on AngularJS",
          "author": "Ari Lerner",
          "cost":4657,
      }];
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

But this is not working, maybe because `filterKey` is not being read correctly in the line `<tr custom-tr ng-repeat="book in books | filter: {filterKey: filterValue}">`.

I suspect so because if I write the keys manually, it works:

```
<tr custom-tr ng-repeat="book in books | filter: {'author': filterValue}">
```

But, this way I'll have to write the filter expression for every key present in the object (what would we do if there were 20 keys?!!).

So, my question is how to implement the search functionality:

- Without trying to emulate the search algorithm myself.
- Without needing to write the filter expression for every key individually

**EDIT:**
I just tried it with multiple fields:

```
<tr custom-tr ng-repeat="book in books | filter: {'author': filterValue} | filter: {'cost': filterValue}">
```

and it is not working at all.
So, what is the correct way to do it anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
  $scope.getFilteredBooks = function() {
    var filter = {};
    filter[$scope.filterKey] = $scope.filterValue;
    return filterFilter($scope.books, filter);
  };
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PmKBk1T8UPycf5nQFtWn?p=preview)

Comment: This is a great solution and is working great!, but it's not a filter, right? Can you explain why my first attempt did not work? And can it be done through filters?

Comment: You can use computed property names which is part of ES2015 and not supported by several modern browsers. You can see the [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Browser_compatibility). Here is the syntax: `"book in books | filter: {[filterKey] :filterValue}`.

Comment: That's great! I think you should add this to the answer; it could be helpful to a lot of people.